# Communicate between remote Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to develop a Chrome extension that will be able to send messages between instances of the extension (i.e. active Chrome browsers with the extension installed around the world) very quickly (like push notifications).

I understand that the regular Chrome messaging (even the external type) only works with extensions installed on the *same* browser, not remote ones.

I'm looking for the best, simplest solution, that will provide quick communication between the clients. The only way I thought about is to get some server running (I don't have one, so I need to find an online service), and run a script that will continuously receive/forward data. Is that the best way? Is there a simpler solution to set up for very simple communication between the remote extension instances?

Comment: I don't see any other way, since a browser can't directly broadcast a message to other browsers in the world, unless I'm mistaken. `I'm looking for the best, simplest solution`, few people look for the worst and slowest solution to their problem ;)

Comment: Maybe you could try PeerJS (to create a peer-to-peer connection) but I'm not sure if it works with Chrome extensions.

Comment: OK thanks, just making sure there wasn't something I'm missing. And @JeremyThille had to make sure you didn't think I'm one of the few ;)

Comment: @Kokodoko thanks, I'll check it out.